# Windows 10 Protected Mode via the Registry, value added when disabled?

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry, windows-10

I am working on a small utility app for my company's enterprise software.

And I came across something odd with Windows 10 and the registry, well maybe it's not odd, and not just a 10 thing.

In all windows versions, it appears to me that the path to the Internet option zone based setting protected mode in the registry is (from memory sorry if I miss one) Current User > Software > Windows > Current Version > Internet settings > Zones and then 1-5 or something.
Normally I find the key 2500 and if its set to a 0, I set it to a 3 to disable protected mode so our software can find the handle of an IE window we use.

What I noticed in Windows 10, was that the key 2500 did not exist in the registry until I disabled it once, then from there 2500 had a 0 or a 3 depending.

So is the key 2500 created (in all versions of windows or just windows 10) when it has first been changed from its default of enabled.
I understand that since the value for enabled is 0, therefore missing the key is the same as reading a 0, but is this the case for all OS's?
I want to know if I should plan on adding the key if it does not exist for only Windows 10 or for all?

Comment: Bad idea.  Protected Mode exists for a reason, you know.

Answer (score -1):

The safest route to take is to assume the key doesn't exist in all versions and create it, if necessary.